# Submatrix view from indices in Eigen

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, numeric, eigen

Is it possible in Eigen to do the equivalent of the following operation in Matlab?

```
A=rand(10,10);
indices = [2,5,6,8,9];

B=A(indices,indices)
```

I want to have a submatrix as a view on the original matrix with given, non consecutive indices.
The best option would be to have a shared memory view of the original matrix, is this possible?

I've figured out a method that works but is not very fast, since it involves non vectorized for loops:

```
MatrixXi slice(const MatrixXi &A, const std::set<int> &indices)
{
    int n = indices.size();
    Eigen::MatrixXi B;
    B.setZero(n,n);

    std::set<int>::const_iterator iInd1 = indices.begin();
    for (int i=0; i<n;++i)
    {
        std::set<int>::const_iterator iInd2=indices.begin();
        for (int j=0; j<n;++j)
        {
            B(i,j) = A.coeffRef(*iInd1,*iInd2);
            ++iInd2;
        }
        ++iInd1;
    }

    return B;
}
```

How can this be made faster?

Comment: 'not very fast'. How fast is it in Matlab and how fast is your implementation? What is your spec? Are you using debug or release mode?

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old, but apparently one can still find it on Google.
So for reference the feature you are looking for is part of the Eigen functionality by now.

```
std::vector<int> ind{4,2,5,5,3};
MatrixXi A = MatrixXi::Random(4,6);
cout << "Initial matrix A:\n" << A << "\n\n";
cout << "A(all,ind):\n" << A(Eigen::placeholders::all,ind) << "\n\n";
```

Example from the Array of indices section in  [Slicing and Indexing](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html) on the Eigen website.

In response to Cris Luengo's comment:
The above slicing returns an [IndexedView](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1IndexedView.html), which is a view on the original data.
Consider the following example code

```
MatrixXd m({{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}});
auto m2 = m({1,3}, {0,2});
m2 = MatrixXd{{0,0},{0,0}};
std::cout << m << std::endl;
```

which returns

```
 1  2  3  4
 0  6  0  8
 9 10 11 12
 0 14  0 16
```

So I guess it produces a shared memory view.

Comment: Does this produce a shared memory view? My guess would be no.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the answer should be yes. I have updated the answer to give more details on the view part.

Comment: MATLAB doesn’t do views, you always get a copy. Indexed assignment is special-case syntax. If you do `b = a([1,2,3]); b(:) = 0` you don’t change `a` because `b` is a copy, not a view.

Comment: In Eigen it appears to be a view. See the updated example.

Answer (score 0):

Make your matrix traversal col-major (which is default in Eigen) http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStorageOrders.html

Disable debug asserts, `EIGEN_NO_DEBUG`, see http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html, as the comment by Deepfreeze suggested.

It is very non-trivial to implement vectorized version since elements are not contiguous in general.  If you are up to it, take a look at AVX2 gather instructions (provided you have CPU with AVX2 support)

To implement matrix view (you called it shared-memory) you'd need to implement an Eigen expression, which is not too hard if you are well versed in C++ and know Eigen codebase.  I can help you to get started if you so want.