# C++ Eigen non-contiguous subsets

Tags: c++, eigen

I am curious about `Eigen::VectorXd` non-contiguous subsets.  For example:

```
Eigen::VectorXd vec = VectorXd::Random(10);
Eigen::VectorXi idx; idx << 2, 5, 6;

Eigen::Block<Eigen::VectorXd> refVec = vec(idx);
```

But this fails to compile.

I have found a few previous questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425331/submatrix-view-from-indices-in-eigen).  However, I have seen on [bugzilla](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=329) that this functionality should now be functional in Eigen which appears to be the syntax I am showing above.

Any insight in how to access non-continguous elements without a `for` loop would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works out of the box if you use the `default` branch and auto:

```
auto refvec = vec(idx);
```

If you really cannot use the devel branch, then follow this [doc page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html#title1).

Comment: So it is still in `devel`.  I thought it was released given the bugzilla comments.  Is there any place to know when it is merged to `master`?

Comment: There is no `master`, strictly speaking it is called `default`, but that's essentially the same, so yes it is already merged, but there is no release yet.

Comment: thanks, is there any timeline for the next release?  I have been trying to subscribe to the eigen mailing list to ask there but keep failing to get a response.

Comment: is the function in the docs a direct reference to the original matrix is it a copy of the indexed elements?

Comment: its a reference, no copy.

Comment: one issue that remains is that there appears to be no assignment operator for the function in the docs.  If I use the `indexing` function it fails if I try to assign new elements (e.g. `Eigen::VectorXd values; refvec = values`).  The compiler fails with `error: no match for 'operator='`.  Perhaps take this conversation off SO?

Comment: Yes, this was just a short example, not a real and complete implementation ! The one in the default branch is several orders of magnitude more sophisticated ;)

Comment: good to know.  That said, is there a timeline on that release?  I can't seem to get on the Eigen mailing list and since I have your attention I would like to ask.